# Auto pick the latest java SE configuration for EBS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

A spring-boot application is deployed to AWS using a cloud -formation script. It fails to deploy the application when the Java SE is updated to a later version giving a similar error as below.

```
No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.1 running Java 8' found.
```

Is it possible to determine the Java SE version supported by the AWS (for EBS) authomatically? Can I retrieve the latest value somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks` from the CLI by giving the region also if it is not configured before. Then you can see whether the above give solution stack is listed. If not you have to raise a ticket to aws, asking them to make the solution stack available in your region. `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.1 running Java 8` is one of the aws new solution stack so use the CLI and make confirm it's available in your region.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried the above command but it displays all the available solution stacks as below. Java SE latest version is also included

Comment: `{      ...........

        "64bit Debian jessie v1.2.1 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)", 

        "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.2 running Java 8", 

        "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.2 running Java 7", 

         ...........
}`

what I would like is to retrieve the latest Java SE from this list of stacks. Is that possible? Thanks